# How to export excel from ReportViewerWebPart manually?

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-excel

I have a ReportViewerWebPart instance in my page and I need to get a excel file from it by code. how can I do that?

p.s: I need to give an excel file from reports, when the visitor click on a button. The embedded menu in ReportViewerWebPart is not proper for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use RS Web Service and do some code by yourself to generate that report. There is a Render method that accepts a file type, just supply the Excel type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx